# java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, glassfish

I am trying to create and run a jsf web app of 'hellow world' in netbeans using glassfish.
I am using netbeans 17. I am using jdk 17 for glassfish 7.

I have jdk 20 and jdk 17 installed. I have glassfish 7 installed and using jdk 17.

The build of the project when created passes but when I try to actually run in I get the following error

> java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @79a13920

Below is the full stack trace

```
Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProvisionException.toProvisionException (InternalProvisionException.java:226)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1053)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters (XStream.java:679)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init> (XStream.java:456)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init> (XStream.java:381)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init> (XStream.java:356)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.WebappStructureSerializer.<clinit> (WebappStructureSerializer.java:47)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.AbstractWarMojo.<init> (AbstractWarMojo.java:324)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.<init> (WarMojo.java:53)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller (Constructor.java:499)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:480)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$ReflectiveProxy.newInstance (DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision (ConstructorInjector.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000 (ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call (ConstructorInjector.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct (ConstructorInjector.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @79a13920
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible (AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible (AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible (Field.java:178)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible (Field.java:172)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.TreeMapConverter.<clinit> (TreeMapConverter.java:59)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters (XStream.java:679)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init> (XStream.java:456)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init> (XStream.java:381)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init> (XStream.java:356)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.WebappStructureSerializer.<clinit> (WebappStructureSerializer.java:47)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.AbstractWarMojo.<init> (AbstractWarMojo.java:324)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.<init> (WarMojo.java:53)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller (Constructor.java:499)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance (Constructor.java:480)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$ReflectiveProxy.newInstance (DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision (ConstructorInjector.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000 (ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call (ConstructorInjector.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct (ConstructorInjector.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  2.836 s
Finished at: 2023-05-18T00:24:47+03:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) on project mavenproject2: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war failed: Unable to load the mojo 'war' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: null
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/Aidel%20Silber/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin/2.3/maven-war-plugin-2.3.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/Aidel%20Silber/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.6/maven-reporting-api-2.0.6.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/Aidel%20Silber/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-7.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/Aidel%20Silber/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.0/commons-cli-1.0.jar
urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/Aidel%20Silber/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/Aidel%20Silber/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.5/maven-archiver-2.5.jar
urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/Aidel%20Silber/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.5/plexus-io-2.0.5.jar
urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/Aidel%20Silber/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.2/plexus-archiver-2.2.jar
urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/Aidel%20Silber/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.15/plexus-interpolation-1.15.jar
urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/Aidel%20Silber/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/Aidel%20Silber/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.3/xstream-1.4.3.jar
urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/Aidel%20Silber/.m2/repository/xmlpull/xmlpull/1.1.3.1/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/Aidel%20Silber/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/Aidel%20Silber/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.8/plexus-utils-3.0.8.jar
urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/Aidel%20Silber/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0-beta-2/maven-filtering-1.0-beta-2.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------
: ExceptionInInitializerError: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @79a13920
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

My pom is as following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>mavenproject2-1.0-SNAPSHOT</name>
    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <jakartaee>10.0.0</jakartaee>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakartaee}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>${jakartaee}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My nb-configuration is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project-shared-configuration>
    <!--
This file contains additional configuration written by modules in the NetBeans IDE.
The configuration is intended to be shared among all the users of project and
therefore it is assumed to be part of version control checkout.
Without this configuration present, some functionality in the IDE may be limited or fail altogether.
-->
    <properties xmlns="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/maven-properties-data/1">
        <!--
Properties that influence various parts of the IDE, especially code formatting and the like. 
You can copy and paste the single properties, into the pom.xml file and the IDE will pick them up.
That way multiple projects can share the same settings (useful for formatting rules for example).
Any value defined here will override the pom.xml file value but is only applicable to the current project.
-->
        <org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_j2eeVersion>10-web</org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_j2eeVersion>
        <org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server>gfv700ee10</org-netbeans-modules-maven-j2ee.netbeans_2e_hint_2e_deploy_2e_server>
        <org-netbeans-modules-projectapi.jsf_2e_language>Facelets</org-netbeans-modules-projectapi.jsf_2e_language>
    </properties>
</project-shared-configuration>
```

I tried setting netbeans to use jdk17 instead of 20.

I tried deleting the repository folder from C:\Users\Username\.m2\repository

Comment: Your version of maven-war-plugin (2.3 from your pom.xml listing) is over 10 years old. Try using a newer version. Also,  GlassFish 7 definitely won't work with JDK 20 in NetBeans. Unless you have a specific reason to be using JDK 20, just use JDK 17 with NetBeans, and also update your question to state which version  of NetBeans is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:**

You are using a very old version of **maven-war-plugin** in your **pom.xml**. Use a recent version instead.

**The Details:**

You correctly cite this as the root cause of your problem:

> java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field
> private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator
> accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed
> module @79a13920

That error arises from your use of a very old version of the maven-war-plugin:

> Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) on
> project mavenproject2: Execution default-war of goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war failed: Unable to
> load the mojo 'war' in the plugin
> 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3' due to an API
> incompatibility

That *"API incompatibility"* is happening because you are using version 2.3 of **maven-war-plugin** which was released in 2012. That precedes by several years the introduction of Java Platform Module System (JPMS) in Java in JDK 9 in 2017.

The war's attempt to access `private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator` was valid (if unwise) with Java 8, but is no longer allowed with JPMS. So just [use a more recent version of maven-war-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin) to resolve this.

Here is the **maven-war-plugin** bug report for this issue, from 2017: [MWAR-405
Workaround XStream incompatibility with Java9](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWAR-405). It states: *"The problem is that XStreams tries to access "comparator" field of java.util.TreeMap and this is forbidden in Java9"*. That is exactly what your stack trace shows.

There is also an open NetBeans Bug Report for an issue very similar to yours. See [need to update maven-war-plugin for maven web application using jdk17 #4552](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/4552). It shows the same error in the stack trace as yours. Note that the bug report cites this as a workaround:
*"work around bump maven-web-plugin to version 3.3.2 in pom.xml"*. (Actually I see that as the solution rather than a workaround, because there is nothing that NetBeans can do to prevent the use of obsolete software.)

Update your question accordingly if using a recent version of **maven-war-plugin** doesn't fix your problem.